# No include path in which to find limits.h: GCC build limits.h (#include_next limits.h)

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, glibc

I am building GCC for a foreign architecture on Ububtu trusty. I am on an i686 and building for i386. I am having the same problem as [GCC build problem (#include_next limits.h)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/871952/608639).

From the discussion in the link I posted this comment struck me as being the best explanation however I am not sure what the poster means by (the toolsets copy)....I suspect he means I need some other tarballs apart from the gcc tarball. I believe I have libc6-dev-x32 and libc6-x32:i386 but these could be something wrong with their installation or something else might be needed?

Can anyone clarify what he means by the toolsets copy?

> Consider using #include_next  (gcc extension) in order to
>   force gcc to look at the next found limits.h in the include path
>   (which should be the toolset's copy).

---

#### Additional Information:

Am I missing part of glibc? I have the packages previously mentioned.

The configure statement is: `./configure --prefix=/testing/gcc2953 --enable-languages=c --target=i486-pc-linux-gnulibc1 --without-headers`

The error message is:

```
In file included from include/syslimits.h:7,
                 from include/limits.h:11,
                 from ./libgcc2.c:1105:
/src/gcc-2.95.3/gcc/include/limits.h:117: No include path in which to find limits.h

make[ 1]: *** [ libgcc2.a] Error 1

make[ 1]: Leaving directory `/src/gcc-2.95.3/gcc'

make: *** [ all-gcc] Error 2
```

Comment: Your title does not describe a problem. Please describe the problem properly, "toolsets copy" simply means "the limits.h file that comes as part of your compiler/standard library". If that's all you wanted to know, you should rather add a comment to your previous question.

Comment: Thanks for responding....there wasn't another version of limits.h in the gcc tarball.  I am not familiar with the include_next directive...so I still don't know what I am missing.  I will post some more details about part of the compiler is being built.                                                                     I will go ahead and modify the question title.

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: Would successful operation be where the next found copy of limits.h that the build needs is the one in glibc?  I installed the packages for libc6-dev-x32 and libc6-x32:i386.  Is another package needed?

Comment: Rather unlikely. The issue is likely that the current glibc header files(and libraries) on your Ubuntu machines simply does not work with/support the 15 year old gcc 2.95 compiler - the fix for this likely is non-trivial, but probably involves finding an old and suitable glibc that you build together with the gcc 2.95 compiler.

Comment: Yes....  I was hoping the glibc was in the two packages libc6-dev-x32 and libc6-x32:i386?

Comment: I see what you are saying. I have got some glibc packages but they are are too recent....

Comment: I would need glibc 2.2.2 (released February 2001)